# Send email using the GMail SMTP server from a PHP page

Tags: php, email, smtp, gmail

I am trying to send an email via GMail's SMTP server from a PHP page, but I get this error:

> authentication failure [SMTP: SMTP server does no support authentication (code: 250, response: mx.google.com at your service, [98.117.99.235] SIZE 35651584 8BITMIME STARTTLS ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES PIPELINING)]

Can anyone help?  Here is my code:

```
<?php
require_once "Mail.php";

$from = "Sandra Sender <sender@example.com>";
$to = "Ramona Recipient <ramona@microsoft.com>";
$subject = "Hi!";
$body = "Hi,\n\nHow are you?";

$host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$port = "587";
$username = "testtest@gmail.com";
$password = "testtest";

$headers = array ('From' => $from,
  'To' => $to,
  'Subject' => $subject);
$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
  array ('host' => $host,
    'port' => $port,
    'auth' => true,
    'username' => $username,
    'password' => $password));

$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
  echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
 } else {
  echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
 }
?>
```

Answer (score 364, accepted):

```
// Pear Mail Library
require_once "Mail.php";

$from = '<fromaddress@gmail.com>';
$to = '<toaddress@yahoo.com>';
$subject = 'Hi!';
$body = "Hi,\n\nHow are you?";

$headers = array(
    'From' => $from,
    'To' => $to,
    'Subject' => $subject
);

$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', array(
        'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
        'port' => '465',
        'auth' => true,
        'username' => 'johndoe@gmail.com',
        'password' => 'passwordxxx'
    ));

$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
    echo('<p>' . $mail->getMessage() . '</p>');
} else {
    echo('<p>Message successfully sent!</p>');
}
```

Comment: what is `Mail.php`?? where do I get this file from?

Comment: could anyone please give me a link where I can get the Mail.php file. Because I tried it and it would not work Thanks

Comment: Would someone please post an example of Mail.php? That is the only piece I am missing, otherwise I believe it will work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where are the @ symbols in this example above? I do not see a single one in there!

Comment: I believe that myaccount.gmail.com is the same as myaccount@gmail.com in the email standards.

Comment: You don't need to include @gmail if you have the server specified.  Just type `myaccount` for username.

Comment: Is there a way to encrypt the password?

Comment: @Xavi : when i use that pear mail package it asks for PEAR.php file

Comment: I'm unable to send mail using the above code. I found the [Mail.php](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail/download) [here](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail/download) but it contains a file `mail` without any extension. Anybody could help?

Comment: If you already installed the PEAR library in debian is in the following directory: /usr/share/php/
You can put something like this, or change php.ini var include_path:
require_once "/usr/share/php/Mail.php";

Comment: This code does not work, it give this error: "SMTP: Invalid response code received from server (code: 535, response: Incorrect authentication data)]"

Comment: use `include_once("Mail.php");` instead of `require_once "Mail.php";`

Comment: Following installation are required to use this code on Ubuntu.
<sudo apt-get install php-pear>
<sudo pear install mail>
<sudo pear install Net_SMTP>

Comment: I'm getting :
    Non-static method Mail::factory() should not be called statically

Please help

Comment: for those who's asking about `Mail.php` They can google `PEAR Library`. While installing `PEAR Library`, be sure to install `PEAR Mail` extension,Thus, `MAIL.PHP`.

Comment: i used your code exactly but i replaced the gmail account with my gmail and passowrd.  for the to and from fields i used:  

    'lmorda2@hotmail.com' => 'ABC'
    'lmorda2@hotmail.com'

am i doing something wrong?  I dont get any emails.

Comment: i think what im trying to ask is can i use anything for the to, from fields?  or does one of them have to be a mail address on my servers domain?  i have one email with my servers domain, and i use google apps for that email.  i dont have a mail server running..

Comment: I tried to send mail as explained. Mail was sent successfully, but it does populate the plain html with "tr" and "td". Can you please help me on this? Mail content will be like <table><tr><td>Name:</td><td>Email:</td></tr></table>

Comment: Download the [latest version **Mail-1.2.0.tgz**](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail/download)  and get the Mail.php from it `\Mail-1.2.0.tgz\Mail-1.2.0.tar\Mail-1.2.0\Mail.php`

Comment: Works very well.  Can I use it to send mass mails ( to notify e-commerce newly added products to subscribed customers) ? for example in for loop. Is it safe ? ( in terms of spam)

Comment: How to get pear.php file to run above code successfully.I am getting "Warning: require_once(PEAR.php): failed to open stream" error while accessing above code in browser.

Comment: To use PEAR packages just add the include path to php like this:
ini_set("include_path", '/home/user/php:' . ini_get("include_path") );

Comment: I am getting `"authentication failure [SMTP: Invalid response code received from server (code: 534, response: 5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and 5.7.14 then try again. 5.7.14 Learn more at 5.7.14 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 p80sm2675348pfk.50 - gsmtp)]"`.

Comment: i am also getting the auth failure like Frayne Konok.  The PHP script is on Ubuntu 14.04 (Digial Ocean server) and the account used to authenticate is a G Suite account that does not end in "@gmail.com". But same account username can log into gmail.

Comment: I have tried all of this thread answer and nothing works for GSuite email that doesnt have @gmail.com. I have looked and tried lot of things of others sites and nothing work. I think the problem is GSuite. If some one has the same issue and could give a solution or point to a web site would be great. I am on a gmail instance using corporative GSuite.

Answer (score 111):

Using [**Swift mailer**](http://swiftmailer.org/), it is quite easy to send a mail through Gmail credentials:

```
<?php
require_once 'swift/lib/swift_required.php';

$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.gmail.com', 465, "ssl")
  ->setUsername('GMAIL_USERNAME')
  ->setPassword('GMAIL_PASSWORD');

$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

$message = Swift_Message::newInstance('Test Subject')
  ->setFrom(array('abc@example.com' => 'ABC'))
  ->setTo(array('xyz@test.com'))
  ->setBody('This is a test mail.');

$result = $mailer->send($message);
?>
```

Comment: This worked "to the first" just changing the GMAIL_USERNAME, GMAIL_PASSWORD, and the From and To addresses. No other solution worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: I agree, swift mailer is a drop in mail solution that much easier than messing with pear. Don't forget to enable PHP's php_openssl extension.

Comment: Nice solution using SwiftMailer! +1

Comment: arrrgh. icant get swiftmailer to work. i dont know how to use that "composer" so i just downloaded the swiftmailer zip from github then I enabled open_ssl then supplied my gmail email and password but it still didnt work.

Comment: ah sorry for my stupidity. you have to open your gmail account because there is an email telling you to enable "less secure app". then its now working heheh

Comment: OpenSSL support enabled
OpenSSL Library Version OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
OpenSSL Header Version OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
But not working yet.

Comment: Finally, Swift Mailer is also the only one that worked for me. I also had some troubles with composer but finally got it. You just install composer for windows then rather then make those json files, just navigate to your direcotry via cmd, then type  "composer require swiftmailer/swiftmailer"

Comment: Swift Mailer is now Symfony Mailer which can be found here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/mailer.html

Answer (score 55):

Your code does not appear to be using TLS (SSL), which is [necessary to deliver mail to Google (and using ports 465 or 587)](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=13287).

You can do this by setting

`$host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";`

Your code looks suspiciously like [this example](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/php-pear-mail-packege-support-security-through-ssl-586976/) which refers to ssl:// in the hostname scheme.

Answer (score 34):

I don't recommend Pear Mail. It has not been updated since 2010. Also read the source files; the source code is almost outdated, written in PHP 4 style and many errors / bugs have been posted (Google it). I am using Swift Mailer.

**Swift Mailer** integrates into any web application written in PHP 5, offering a flexible and elegant object-oriented approach to sending emails with a multitude of features.

> Send emails using SMTP, sendmail, postfix or a custom Transport
> implementation of your own.
>
> Support servers that require username & password and/or encryption.
>
> Protect from header injection attacks without stripping request data
> content.
>
> Send MIME compliant HTML/multipart emails.
>
> Use event-driven plugins to customize the library.
>
> Handle large attachments and inline/embedded images with low memory
> use.

It is a free and open source you can [**Download Swift Mailer**](http://swiftmailer.org/download) and upload to your server. (The feature list is copied from owner website).

The working example of Gmail SSL/SMTP and Swift Mailer is here...

```
// Swift Mailer Library
require_once '../path/to/lib/swift_required.php';

// Mail Transport
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('ssl://smtp.gmail.com', 465)
    ->setUsername('username@gmail.com') // Your Gmail Username
    ->setPassword('my_secure_gmail_password'); // Your Gmail Password

// Mailer
$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

// Create a message
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance('Wonderful Subject Here')
    ->setFrom(array('sender@example.com' => 'Sender Name')) // can be $_POST['email'] etc...
    ->setTo(array('receiver@example.com' => 'Receiver Name')) // your email / multiple supported.
    ->setBody('Here is the <strong>message</strong> itself. It can be text or <h1>HTML</h1>.', 'text/html');

// Send the message
if ($mailer->send($message)) {
    echo 'Mail sent successfully.';
} else {
    echo 'I am sure, your configuration are not correct. :(';
}
```

Comment: This no longer works, I always get the return message "535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted". My credentials are fine and I have set the "allow less-secure apps" to ON. Anyone know a fix to this?

Comment: Swift doesn't seem to work in PHP 5.x - doesn't understand the ?? coalesce - just blows up.

Answer (score 28):

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Toronto');

require_once('class.phpmailer.php');
//include("class.smtp.php"); // optional, gets called from within class.phpmailer.php if not already loaded

$mail             = new PHPMailer();

$body             = "gdssdh";
//$body             = eregi_replace("[\]",'',$body);

$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
//$mail->Host       = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com"; // SMTP server
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 1;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
                                           // 1 = errors and messages
                                           // 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";                 // sets the prefix to the servier
$mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";      // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
$mail->Port       = 465;                   // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
$mail->Username   = "user@gmail.com";  // GMAIL username
$mail->Password   = "password";            // GMAIL password

$mail->SetFrom('contact@prsps.in', 'PRSPS');

//$mail->AddReplyTo("user2@gmail.com', 'First Last");

$mail->Subject    = "PRSPS password";

//$mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test

$mail->MsgHTML($body);

$address = "user2@yahoo.co.in";
$mail->AddAddress($address, "user2");

//$mail->AddAttachment("images/phpmailer.gif");      // attachment
//$mail->AddAttachment("images/phpmailer_mini.gif"); // attachment

if(!$mail->Send()) {
  echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  echo "Message sent!";
}

?>
```

Comment: Why do you set the host twice and which one is the right one?

Comment: Where do I get the class.phpmailer.php file?? Pasting code only is not so helpful pls include more description on the code too!

Comment: While some of the syntax is outdated, PHPMailer ended up being the best solution for me, +1

Answer (score 22):

As of **May 30, 2022**, [Google **will no longer support**](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en) the use of third-party applications and devices that allow you to sign in to your Google Account with your **username and password**.

However, there is an easy solution provided by Google.

Instead of a password, input an **app password** generated by Google. Firstly, go to the settings and enable `2-Step Verification`.

[image]

Then click on the `App passwords`.

[image]

You should see the App passwords screen. *App passwords let you sign in to your Google Account from apps on devices that don't support 2-Step Verification*. Select `Mail` as the app and then select a device. In my case, I chose `Other`, because I want to deploy my application to the cloud.

[image]

Once done, click on the `GENERATE` button. You will see your generated app password.

[image]

Just copy the password and replace the previous password in your email sending service with the generated one. You won't be able to see the password again though.

That's it!

Comment: This method works, thanks! Ensure the SMTP server is `smtp.gmail.com` and you're all set.

Comment: Great, simple but effective.

Answer (score 20):

[SwiftMailer](http://www.swiftmailer.org) can send E-Mail using external servers.

here is an example that shows how to use a Gmail server:

```
require_once "lib/Swift.php";
require_once "lib/Swift/Connection/SMTP.php";

//Connect to localhost on port 25
$swift =& new Swift(new Swift_Connection_SMTP("localhost"));


//Connect to an IP address on a non-standard port
$swift =& new Swift(new Swift_Connection_SMTP("217.147.94.117", 419));


//Connect to Gmail (PHP5)
$swift = new Swift(new Swift_Connection_SMTP(
    "smtp.gmail.com", Swift_Connection_SMTP::PORT_SECURE, Swift_Connection_SMTP::ENC_TLS));
```

Answer (score 14):

The code as listed in the question needs two changes

```
$host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
$port = "465";
```

Port 465 is required for an SSL connection.

Answer (score 8):

Send Mail using phpMailer library through Gmail
Please donwload library files from [Github](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)

```
<?php
/**
 * This example shows settings to use when sending via Google's Gmail servers.
 */
//SMTP needs accurate times, and the PHP time zone MUST be set
//This should be done in your php.ini, but this is how to do it if you don't have access to that
date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');
require '../PHPMailerAutoload.php';
//Create a new PHPMailer instance
$mail = new PHPMailer;
//Tell PHPMailer to use SMTP
$mail->isSMTP();
//Enable SMTP debugging
// 0 = off (for production use)
// 1 = client messages
// 2 = client and server messages
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
//Ask for HTML-friendly debug output
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
//Set the hostname of the mail server
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
// use
// $mail->Host = gethostbyname('smtp.gmail.com');
// if your network does not support SMTP over IPv6
//Set the SMTP port number - 587 for authenticated TLS, a.k.a. RFC4409 SMTP submission
$mail->Port = 587;
//Set the encryption system to use - ssl (deprecated) or tls
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
//Whether to use SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
//Username to use for SMTP authentication - use full email address for gmail
$mail->Username = "username@gmail.com";
//Password to use for SMTP authentication
$mail->Password = "yourpassword";
//Set who the message is to be sent from
$mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'First Last');
//Set an alternative reply-to address
$mail->addReplyTo('replyto@example.com', 'First Last');
//Set who the message is to be sent to
$mail->addAddress('whoto@example.com', 'John Doe');
//Set the subject line
$mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer GMail SMTP test';
//Read an HTML message body from an external file, convert referenced images to embedded,
//convert HTML into a basic plain-text alternative body
$mail->msgHTML(file_get_contents('contents.html'), dirname(__FILE__));
//Replace the plain text body with one created manually
$mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';
//Attach an image file
$mail->addAttachment('images/phpmailer_mini.png');
//send the message, check for errors
if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Message sent!";
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I had this problem also. I set the correct settings and have enabled less secure apps but it still did not work. Finally, I enabled this https://accounts.google.com/UnlockCaptcha, and it worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

Gmail requires port 465, and also it's the code from phpmailer

Answer (score 4):

To install PEAR's Mail.php in Ubuntu, run following set of commands:

```
    sudo apt-get install php-pear
    sudo pear install mail
    sudo pear install Net_SMTP
    sudo pear install Auth_SASL
    sudo pear install mail_mime
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but it's still active and all the answers I saw showed basic authentication, which is deprecated. Here is an example showing how to send email using SMTP via Google's Gmail servers using PHPMailer with XOAUTH2 authentication:

```
//Import PHPMailer classes into the global namespace
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\OAuth;
//Alias the League Google OAuth2 provider class
use League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Google;

//SMTP needs accurate times, and the PHP time zone MUST be set
//This should be done in your php.ini, but this is how to do it if you don't have access to that
date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');

//Load dependencies from composer
//If this causes an error, run 'composer install'
require '../vendor/autoload.php';

//Create a new PHPMailer instance
$mail = new PHPMailer();

//Tell PHPMailer to use SMTP
$mail->isSMTP();

//Enable SMTP debugging
//SMTP::DEBUG_OFF = off (for production use)
//SMTP::DEBUG_CLIENT = client messages
//SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER = client and server messages
$mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;

//Set the hostname of the mail server
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';

//Set the SMTP port number:
// - 465 for SMTP with implicit TLS, a.k.a. RFC8314 SMTPS or
// - 587 for SMTP+STARTTLS
$mail->Port = 465;

//Set the encryption mechanism to use:
// - SMTPS (implicit TLS on port 465) or
// - STARTTLS (explicit TLS on port 587)
$mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS;

//Whether to use SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;

//Set AuthType to use XOAUTH2
$mail->AuthType = 'XOAUTH2';

//Fill in authentication details here
//Either the gmail account owner, or the user that gave consent
$email = 'someone@gmail.com';
$clientId = 'RANDOMCHARS-----duv1n2.apps.googleusercontent.com';
$clientSecret = 'RANDOMCHARS-----lGyjPcRtvP';

//Obtained by configuring and running get_oauth_token.php
//after setting up an app in Google Developer Console.
$refreshToken = 'RANDOMCHARS-----DWxgOvPT003r-yFUV49TQYag7_Aod7y0';

//Create a new OAuth2 provider instance
$provider = new Google(
    [
        'clientId' => $clientId,
        'clientSecret' => $clientSecret,
    ]
);

//Pass the OAuth provider instance to PHPMailer
$mail->setOAuth(
    new OAuth(
        [
            'provider' => $provider,
            'clientId' => $clientId,
            'clientSecret' => $clientSecret,
            'refreshToken' => $refreshToken,
            'userName' => $email,
        ]
    )
);

//Set who the message is to be sent from
//For gmail, this generally needs to be the same as the user you logged in as
$mail->setFrom($email, 'First Last');

//Set who the message is to be sent to
$mail->addAddress('someone@gmail.com', 'John Doe');

//Set the subject line
$mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer GMail XOAUTH2 SMTP test';

//Read an HTML message body from an external file, convert referenced images to embedded,
//convert HTML into a basic plain-text alternative body
$mail->CharSet = PHPMailer::CHARSET_UTF8;
$mail->msgHTML(file_get_contents('contentsutf8.html'), __DIR__);

//Replace the plain text body with one created manually
$mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';

//Attach an image file
$mail->addAttachment('images/phpmailer_mini.png');

//send the message, check for errors
if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message sent!';
}
```

Reference: [PHPMailer examples folder](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail_xoauth.phps)

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution for GSuite accounts that doesnt have the "@gmail.com" sufix. Also I think it will work for GSuite accounts with the @gmail.com but havent tried it. 
First you should have the privileges to change the option "allos¿w less secure app" for your GSuite account. If you have the privileges (you can check in account settings->security) then you have to deactivate "two step factor authentication" go to the end of the page and set to "yes" for allow less secure applications. That's all. If you dont have privileges to change those options the solution for this thread will not work. Check https://support.google.com/a/answer/6260879?hl=en to make changes to "allow less..." option.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the suggestion offered by @shasi kanth, but it didn't work out. I read the documentation and there are few changes made. So I managed to send mail via Gmail using this code, where vendor/autoload.php is got by composer with composer require "swiftmailer/swiftmailer:^6.0":

```
<?php
     require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
     $transport = (new Swift_SmtpTransport('smtp.gmail.com', 465, 'ssl'))->setUsername ('SendingMail')->setPassword ('Password');

     $mailer = new Swift_Mailer($transport);

     $message = (new Swift_Message('test'))
      ->setFrom(['Sending mail'])
      ->setTo(['Recipient mail'])
      ->setBody('Message')
  ;

     $result = $mailer->send($message);
    ?>
```

Answer (score -5):

Set

```
'auth' => false,
```

Also, see if port 25 works.

Comment: It won't - Google requires delivery on 465 or 587.  See http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=13287.